# How to replace path parameter in URL NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, url

**Problem Statement:** To replace path parameter in URL before making a call to API in NodeJS(Javascript) based API automation framework.

*Given URL:* `https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/{id}`

`{id}` needs to be replaced with value `Sunshine`

**Expected URL:**  `https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/Sunshine`

I have seen certain questions in StackOverflow. But they are more related to replace `query_params` value but not to replace `path_params`.

I am trying to do with this approach, but this code does not work.

```
var href = new URL('https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/{id}');
href.searchParams.set('{id}', 'Sunshine');
console.log(href.toString());
```

Any help to let me know how to do this would be of great help.

Comment: share code sample.

Comment: Edited with code @mehta-rohan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This cannot be done with the `URL` API, you'll have to do a string replacement instead:

```js
var href = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/{id}'.replace('{id}', 'Sunshine');
console.log(href);
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked. Sometimes we miss basic concepts :)